# Getting file with space in string from sftp through bash script

Tags: bash, sftp

I have a bash script to get a file from a remote sftp site, the file has a space in the name (this can't be changed)

```
!/bin/bash
filename="$(echo "ls -tr" | sftp -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa username@host:/tmp/myfiles | tail -n 1)"
cmd="get /tmp/myfiles/$filename"
echo "'$cmd'" | sftp -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa username@host:/tmp/myfiles
```

I get the error

```
user on host ~/scripts in /home
14:32:45 » ./get_files.sh
Connected to host.
get /tmp/myfiles/User data_20230330_103101.csv
Connected to host.
Changing to: /tmp/myfiles
Invalid command.
sftp> 'get /tmp/myfiles/User data_20230330_103101.csv              '
File "get /tmp/myfiles/User data_20230330_103101.csv              " not found.
```

I can see it complains about whitespace after the filename, but can't figure out where this is coming from? I can log onto the sftp server and ls which shows the file is present, but not with the trailing whitespace that I can't find where it comes from.

Comment: The quotes need to be around the filename, not the whole command.

Comment: And think about using herestrings -- `sftp ... <<<'ls -ltr'` instead of `echo 'ls -ltr' | sftp ...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're quoting the wrong thing, and your filename variable has whitespace on the end.

Change

```
cmd="get /tmp/myfiles/$filename"
```

to

```
shopt -s extglob # note, this requires a *bash* script not a *sh* script
filename=${filename%%+([[:space:]])} # remove trailing spaces from filename
cmd="get '/tmp/myfiles/$filename'"
```

and then change `echo "'$cmd'"` to `echo "$cmd"`

Comment: Perfect, works now. Thanks!